# Is Xamarin Forms ready for Production usage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been learning Xamarin for the past few months and while I've been mainly using PCL projects I'm excited to start using Xamarin forms.

My one hesitation is if it is ready for production sized uses. 
Does it have the specificity needed or is it a case of writing some custom custom renderer/control to get by?

From what I have researched so far it seems that developers are happy with it but they all talk about having to add customs features, which would be above my skill level at this time.

Any insight in the progression of xamarin forms would be really helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is ready for production usage as there are a number of apps available that use it. For example the recent Xamarin Evolve conference had a companion app written in Forms, and the source is freely available if you wanted to grab it and have a look.

Forms gives you a lot out of the box, but not everything. It is a bit of a 'lowest common denominator' tool providing features that are common to both platforms but as you say you can always write custom renderers to access platform specific stuff.

One cool thing to be aware of is that in the preview versions there is code for doing things like putting native controls into your XAML and these only show on the correct platform. This is an area that is constantly growing, there's code coming that allow you to tweak properties on the underlying platform controls inside your shared XAML, just by tagging the property as relevant only to one platform.

Xamarin are targeting Forms more and more for beginners to the platform. They've shown this by changing their XamU to be more forms focussed, and their internal blog covers Forms more than anything else. It's good enough for most things now, but is getting better fast. Honestly if I was building a brand new app now I would seriously consider Forms unless the app needed heavy platform specific UI customisations.

Comment: I would also add that Xamarin.Forms's lowest denominator quality is very satisfying if you build internal/business apps. But if you're targeting a certain audience on the AppStore and your business model will based on sales then you may want to build "native" UI's to be able to make something that looks pixel-perfect. 
But more and more apps will be internal/business/for productivity and for these apps Xamarin.Forms is really good enough.

Comment: One thing to consider is Forms first, then change to native if you need it. If you build your app well, using something like MVVM with a framework that supports both native and Forms (such as MvvmCross) you could start with a Forms app, and if you need to change it's only the thin view layer you have to re-write.

Comment: We (JobAdder) have had a Xamarin.Forms built in production for roughly 2 years now. It is most definitely a production ready technology. Like all techs, it has its quirks and issues but once you establish a baseline knowledge of Forms it is possible to make amazing apps with it.

Comment: @matthewrdev do you find yourself having to use custom renders much in your Forms production app or does forms cover enough?

Comment: For the most part we don't need to use custom renderers and forms or 3rd party controls cover what we need. Custom renderers aren't too hard to implement once you're familiar with the apis. Also, XF 2.3.3 introduced native view declaration which allows you to pull in native controls without using custom renderers.

Comment: awesome Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries, if you have any more q's my twitter details are on my profile so get in contact :)

Answer (score 2):

Coming back to this thread after a years experience in the framework I can confidently say yes it is ready for production usage.
Especially when coupled with mvvm frameworks such a prism etc. 
Also the introduction of native forms and native embedding is gradually allowing developers to use both in the same project which is awesome in my opinion.